# Spaces instead ascii character

Tags: c++, windows-7, visual-c++-2010

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    for(int i=0;i<18;i++)
       std::cout << (char)i << '\n';
}
```

OUTPUT is:
[image]

But where are other characters?
[image]

Comment: Those are in no way ASCII characters. Looks more like CP437.

Comment: Oh, they're ASCII. But they're [control characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii#ASCII_control_characters).

Comment: @FredLarson: No, they're not. The ASCII control characters have no visual presentation. A smiley face is clearly a visual presentation, and clearly not part of ASCII.

Comment: Well, I was just going by the codes. There apparently should be some glyphs in the question but I can't see them.

Comment: In the [IBM PC Extended ASCII Display Characters](http://www.jimprice.com/ascii-dos.gif) the "other" characters are also missing...

Comment: @Wimmel, There we go, fits perfectly. There are too many of these things :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The characters you are expecting to see are not ASCII.  In ASCII, the codes below 32 signify what is called control characters, which were originally intended to control functions on teletype printers.  Many of them don't apply to modern terminals, so your terminal just picked some characters (or got them from some other encoding), such as the faces and the card suits, to use for those codes. Some of the ASCII control characters are still applicable though.

- 7 is a called the bell character (`'\a'`), you may have heard a beep.
- 8 is a backspace (`'\b'`).

  `std::cout << "abc" << (char)8 "def"; // where's the c?`
- 9 is a horizontal tab (`'\t'`), so that's invisible, but you'll probably notice it if you print visible characters before and after it.

  `std::cout << "before" << (char)9 << "after";`
- 10 is a line feed, a.k.a. newline (`'\n'`)
- 13 is a carriage return (`'\r'`).

  `std::cout << "hello" << (char)13 << "world"; // where's the hello?`

Your results may vary depending upon which terminal you use.